# Kubuntu: Using Wayland / Nvidia / KDE on 21.04

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, wayland, debug, 21.04

I've just updated Kubuntu from 20.10 to 21.04. When trying to start a new session with Wayland it freezes at the vendor splash screen. How would I go about it to debug this? Suspecting it might has to to with the fact that I got a Nvidia-card. Many thanks!

Comment: What card and drivers?

Comment: Its GTX 1650. Will have to check driver and get back.

Comment: GTX1650 should be running with 460.xx drivers. This version doesn't support wayland AFAIK. Only the very latest Nvidia drivers (you can't use those) have experimental support for wayland.

Comment: Thank you all for the response. My driver number is 450.119.03

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://community.kde.org/Plasma/Wayland/Nvidia and use a beta nvidia driver (see https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu). I was able to reach the desktop. From there though, things did not go well. The nvidia settings app window does not open correctly, some menu windows do not display correctly and some applications do not start. Kde 5.22 (not in 21.04 by default) is supposed to do a better job...